# WP7 how to call Pivot from a class?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a `Pivot` on *MainPage.xaml*; how can I call this from another class?

```
MainPage.mypivot.Items.Add(p);


Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, 
or property '...MainPage.mypivot'   H:\Users\Lacroix\documents\...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that exactly because of the reason the compiler tells you. *MainPage* is not a static class, when you view the page an instance of the class is being displayed, so you need to manipulate that instance. What you can do is pass a reference to the *MainPage* class to the other class. Then have *MainPage* contain an instance of the other class.

In *MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  private MyClass _myClass;

  MainPage()
  {
    _myClass = new MyClass( this );

  }
}
```

Now, `MyClass` will have access to the `Pivot` (and all other elements of *MainPage*).

If whatever logic the other class uses to add items to the `Pivot` is not available when displaying *MainPage*, i.e. you need to add items when displaying some other page, you'll need to create a static list (say `PivotItemsList`) in the `App` class. Have the other class add items to this list instead of directly to the `Pivot`. You can then access this within the *MainPage* constructor as `App.PivotItemsList` and add the items to the `Pivot`.